# Problem passing strings with PHP post

Tags: php, post

Basically I'm developing a (very) simple search engine. You can enter a search term and you are taken to the results page - which works fine. However on the results page, I have a button that will take you to the next 10 results: where $term is the $_POST['term'] value.

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='term' value='" . $term . "'>";
```

This causes the following problem with the term is for example "aidan's".

When the next 10 button is clicked, the term becomes aidan\ and no further results are found.

I am not doing anything to $term.

I usually use Java, but am required to use PHP for this uni assignment!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It could be your PHP that escapes your data, check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc and / or http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php these should help you to identify the porblem

Answer (score 0):

Try looking after addslashes() et stripslashes()
http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Regarding your issue, I think you should try to add something like this :

```
$search = stripslashes($_POST['term']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use double quotes, you don't have to break your string when using a variable. You can also use various options, such as those mentioned already or `htmlentities()` or `urlencode()`. I would use the later, just cuz. So you would end up with:

```
$term = urlencode($term);
echo "<input type='hidden' name='term' value=\"$term\">";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `htmlspecialchars()` **every single bit of data** you output to your page. A set-up like yours is the reason that so many XSS vulnerabilities exist around the world, and you should not contribute to them.

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='term' value='" . htmlspecialchars($term) . "'>";
```

Once you have that, you will need no obscure addslashes/quote escaping/whatever anymore.

To make that easier throughout your code, define

```
function h($s) {  htmlspecialchars($s); }

echo "<input type='hidden' name='term' value='" . h($term) . "'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is `htmlspecialchars()`. However to make it work, you must use quotation marks to wrap the parameter.

Plus, if there are slashes involved, the `stripslashes()` function may be needed.

So:

```
$term = htmlspecialchars( stripslashes( $term ) );

echo '<input type="text" name="term" value="' . $term . '" >';
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Always use GET method for the search, not POST.
2. Either turn magic quotes off or strip slashes manually
3. Use htmllspecialchars with ENT_QUOTES parameter to encode form's field value.
4. Consider to print out HTML as is, not using PHP echo, to get rid of all this quotes craze
5. **Most important part**.  If you quote your term for the database search, don't use quoted variable in your form.

so

```
if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
  if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $_GET['term'] = stripslashes($_GET['term']);
  //$term=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['term']);
  //perform search here. 
  //
  $term = htmlspecialchars($_GET['term'],ENT_QUOTES); //from $_GET again
  ?>
  <input type="hidden" name="term" value="<?php echo $term?>">
  <?
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest way is not to put $term as a hidden field at all. For pagination, you can keep memory of the searched term in the session.

Comment: wrong idea. none of search engines use sessions to pass a search string for obvious reasons.

Comment: What are the obvious reasons? Excuse my naif question, but I do not see problems with that.